# Assigning an element of a pointer to another element from the same pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, string-literals

I'm trying to assign an element from a pointer the same value as another element from the same pointer.

```
int testFunc() {
    char *p = "123";
    p[0] = p[2];
    return 0;
}
```

Curious as to why the above code doesn't work - and what is the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You hardly want to "assign an element from a pointer the same value as another element from the same pointer", but from the objects they **point to**! Also you want to read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: This code attempts to modify a string literal (which is undefined behavior) on a string that nothing outside of the function has access to; what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Olaf There is nothing wrong with the question as far as SO policies go. The code posted contains a MCVE. The only problem here is the lack of research before asking a FAQ.

Comment: @Lundin: I miss what OP expects and what he gets. "Doesn't work" is not a specific statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing the issue because you're trying to modify a *[string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)* which  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The problem is in

```
 p[0] = p[2];
```

while `p` points to a *string literal*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, *String literals*

> [...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

You need to have an array instead, t be able to modify the contents, something like

```
 char parr[] = "123";
```

and then

```
 parr[0] = parr[2];
```

will do.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `char *p = "123"`, `p` points to the first element of 4 characters of *read-only* memory. Really you should write `const char* p = "123"` to induce a compile-time failure on the statement `p[0] = p[2];`.

If you want to modify the string then use automatic storage duration; i.e. write

`char[] p = "123";`

`p` is then a `char[4]` type, with a nul-terminator for the final element.

Comment: The standard does not require the memory to be read-only. It just says it must not be changed by the programmer. But then it allows implementations to provide modifyable memory.

Answer (score 0):

> char *p = "123";

When you define a pointer like this it will save the data in *read-only memory segment*, that is the reason you are not able to modify the data